# How can i return twice same name of filed for different tables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My request works in MYSQLWorkbench and in PHP too but when I want to return a value of the field in PHP it can't return because it's has the same name of another filed in another table.

This is Code PHP :

```
<?php
    foreach ( $sql as $x => $y ) :
?>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td><? echo $y['s']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['s']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['name']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['name']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['wei ']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
endforeach;?>
```

This's my query :

```
$r = "SELECT  
            pro.cs.s,
            n_p.s as xs,
            pro.cas.name as name_cas,
            pro.cc.name as name_c, 
            pro.cs.wei as weight

     FROM n_p

     LEFT JOIN pro.cs ON n_p.s = pro.cs.xs 
     LEFT JOIN pro.cc ON pro.cs.fk_cc = pro.cc.id_cc
     LEFT JOIN pro.cas ON pro.cc.fk_cas = pro.cas.id_cas";
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What value? Which table? How are you getting those values?

Comment: Show the query you are using. But in general if you are getting a column with the same name from 2 or more different tables you need to rename one of them like `SELECT a.id, b.id as b_id`

Comment: @b0s3 my request works in  mysqlworkbench and  php also. I have table in PHP that should return all fields that i select in my request because i have same field name in two differents tables it returned nothing.

Comment: Normally it returns both but because PHP converts the selected rows column names to either array occurrances or object properties one of the columns gets used twice in the array or object and you only see the value from the last column listed in the select

Comment: Show us your query!!! Edit your question and add it in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i have already done but its not working.

Comment: Have you also changed one of the `echo $p['s']` to `echo $p['s_x']` or whatever you renamed the column to

Comment: I have never seen dots used in table names before, didnt know you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where `$p` gets set to anything or why you are in a foreach loop that uses `$sql` as the array but, using your logic and assuming its correct

change your php like this

```
<?php
    foreach ( $sql as $x => $y ) :
?>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td><? echo $y['s']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['xs']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['name_cas']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['name_c']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $y['weight']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
endforeach;?>
```

Comment: It does not help that you keep changing your question, but the above should give you the basic idea

Answer (score -2):

You are echoing $p variable which doesn't exist in what you have sent.

Comment: @Jumes Thanks for your answer. it's just a mistake of copy and paste it wasen't  the cause of what im asking. Anyway i solved my problem